# Extracting an optional project name in a fully optional pattern

Tags: regex, capturing-group

I have this string `"https://url/projects/x/flow/"` and i want:

1. if projects is existing in the string, capture x  in a group named project_name
2. if projects not existing in the string, then capture the whole string

The regex i am using is `"\S*(projects\/(?<project_name>\w+))?"`

But x is not captured and stored in a capturing group. Not sure what is wrong with my regex.
Your help is appreciated

Comment: Does `^(?:\S*?(projects\/(?<project_name>\w+)))?.*` help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
^(?:\S*?(projects\/(?<project_name>\w+)))?.*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/emchCq/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:\S*?(projects\/(?<project_name>\w+)))?` - an optional non-capturing group:

  - `\S*?` - any zero or more non-whitespace chars, as few as possible
  - `(projects\/(?<project_name>\w+))` - Group 1: `projects/` + one or more word chars after it captured into "project_name" group
- `.*` - the rest of the string.